# Mapping something correctly in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json Data which looks like this

```
0: (963) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
1: (964) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
2: (954) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
```

where my data looks like this

```
[0 … 99]
0: {y: 0, x: 10.7279501}
1: {y: 0, x: 10.73239994}
2: {y: 0, x: 10.73684978}
3: {y: 0, x: 10.7413168}
4: {y: 0, x: 10.74576664}
5: {y: 0, x: 10.7502327}
```

Now, I am trying to use plotly, the plotly documentation for react states just this example

```
<Plot
        data={[
          {
            x: [1, 2, 3],
            y: [2, 6, 3],
            type: 'scatter',
            mode: 'lines+points',
            marker: {color: 'red'},
          },

      />
```

The above just to plot data for single graph, but if I do something like this

```
      <Plot  
                data={[
                    {
                      x: [1, 2, 3],
                      y: [2, 6, 3],
                      type: 'scatter',
                      mode: 'lines+points',
                      marker: {color: 'red'},
                    },
                    {
                        x: [2, 5, 3],
                        y: [2, 8, 3],
                        type: 'scatter',
                        mode: 'lines+points',
                        marker: {color: 'red'},
                      }
                    ]}
                />
```

I can plot multiple data.

Now, Can someone help me in mapping my data such that I can create multiple graphs?

or the least can someone please help me in figuring out how can I create multiple object inside array using map

```
{
//data 
}, 
{
//data1
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
data={[
                    this.graphdata.map((data, index) => ({

                            x: data["x"],
                            y: data["y"],
                            type: 'scatter',
                            mode: 'lines+points',
                            marker: {color: 'red'},
                }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `graphdata` equals this:

```
0: (963) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
1: (964) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
2: (954) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
```

Then you would have to do:

```
graphdata.map(data => {
  // at this point data equals [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
  return {
    x: data.map(point => point.x),
    y: data.map(point => point.y),
    type: 'scatter',
    mode: 'lines+points',
    marker: {color: 'red'},
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an **extended version** of [J. Hesters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8331756/j-hesters) solution above.
You must store the new array returned by the `.map` method in a new variable, let's say, `plottableData`.

```
const plottableData = graphdata.map(data => ({
    x: data.map(point => point.x),
    y: data.map(point => point.y),
    type: 'scatter',
    mode: 'lines+points',
    marker: { color: 'red' },
}));
```

Then, you can use the `plottableData` in your code as follows-

```
<Plot data={plottableData} />
```

Or

```
<Plot data={[...plottableData]} />
```

Hope this will also be helpful!